# How much information is in a message?

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, formal-languages, entropy

I understand that information is the measure of "surprise" to register a particular outcome so it has something to do with the recipient of the message.

In the case where I told a machine something like "Sam likes cake." how would I be able to quantify the information in that message? I could consider that there is a mechanism insides it that can calculate the probabilities of what I say to be either true or false, but then what? I can define:

Given a probability distribuition $\{p(x_{k})\}_{k≤n}$ then the information associated to measuring a particular outcome is $I=−log_{2}(p(x_{k}))$, that a message is string of binary code that minimizes the length of an sentence in english as much as it can in these $0$s and $1$s, and that what I mean by the machine "knowing" is that its able to map the message to an event in a list it has, each having a certain probability of happening.

Do I just take the log of the inverse of that probability and say that's the amount of information? What do I do? It somehow feels like the amount of information would depend on

- The difference between what it has currently mapped
- The likelihood to recieve that specific message

But I don't know how you would go about matching both of these to come up with the information.

Comment: Information in the sense of ordinary information theory is not well-suited to answering this kind of question. As you say it depends on a choice of probability distribution and it's not obvious where this is supposed to come from. There is a different definition of information coming from algorithmic information theory that is more relevant (although it has the unfortunate deficit of being uncomputable): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory In particular it is really defined for a single message, with no choice of probability distribution necessary.

Comment: But, shouldn't it be able to represent the same as our ordinary information? If we can take the probability distribution for granted then what could be a way to solve this in thr context of regular information theory?